# Quill: How to prevent toolbar from scrolling and set the height?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, quill

I am trying to follow the sample at https://quilljs.com/playground/#autogrow-height but have problems setting the height of the editor box and preventing the toolbar from scrolling off-screen.

My code is:

```
<div id="editorcontainer" style="height:10em; min-height:100%; overflow-y:auto;">
   <div id="editor" name="editor" style="min-height:100%; height:auto;"></div>
</div>

<script>
  var quill = new Quill("#editor",{
     modules: {
       toolbar: [ ... ]
         },
         scrollingContainer: "#editorcontainer",
         theme: "snow"
     });
</script>
```

The JS Filddle is available at https://jsfiddle.net/OldGeezer/xpvt214o/556844/

The output looks like this:

[image]

There are two problems:

1. The tool bar is not fixed and scrolls.
2. The vertical scrollbar has a scrollable region all the time, even when the editor is empty.

How do I solve these two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to add an additional encapsulating `div` with `position:relative` to establish the reference frame for `ql-toolbar` which is set to `position:absolute`.

The `editorcontainer` is then given a `margin-top:3em` to hold the toolbar (when it is short enough to fill a single row).

```
<div style="position:relative;margin-top:5em;">
  <div id="editorcontainer" style="height:10em; min-height:100%; 
         overflow-y:auto;margin-top:3em">
     <div id="editor" style="min-height:100%; height:auto;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .ql-toolbar { position: absolute; top: 0;left:0;right:0}
</style>
```

The working fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/OldGeezer/oLq2bnzv/

Answer (score 14):

I had to modify two of quill's classes to get what I wanted. Like so

```
.ql-container.ql-snow {
    height: auto;
}
.ql-editor {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: [JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/h8g79yxu/)

Comment: This works just fine . But can you share how to make the toolbar sticky while the editor is at 100% height?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify one of quill's class

```
.ql-container.ql-snow {
  border: none;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who suffered from Angular quill in this question,

I suggest you should add this code in the style.css.

```
.ql-toolbar {
  position: sticky;
}

.ql-container {
  overflow-x:auto;
  height: 300px; /* whatever you what */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> 1. The tool bar is not fixed and scrolls.

You can change the CSS of the toolbar like the following:

```
.ql-toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

> 2. The vertical scrollbar has a scrollable region all the time, even when the editor is empty.

You can lower the `min-height` of the editor so it's lower than the container (80% for example).

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work properly. The two styles cause the toolbar to stick to the top of the physical page, and the toolbar bounding box is shrunk to fit only the visible items instead of spanning full horizontal width.  Can you try and fork my JS fiddle?